# Chocolat: How to see Build or Run output for C/C++/ObjC?

Tags: text-editor

**My Setup**:
*Chocolat v1.2

OS X 10.7.4*

I'm using [Chocolat](http://chocolatapp.com/) to write C/C++/ObjC code. I have saved the file I am working on with the appropriate file extension (e.g. `.c`, `.m`, etc) such that Chocolat correctly recognizes the type of code I am writing.

When I select the **Build** or **Run** menu items, nothing seems to happen.

Is it possible to see **Build** or **Run** results in some kind of output or console window in Chocolat? Specifically, I'm curious about C/ObjC/C++, but also curious if there is a more general feature for this in Chocolat.

I was kind of expecting that when I **Build**, I would be able to see compiler or lint output in some kind of window or console. And when I **Run**, I would see `stdout` and `stderr` output. Does this feature exist in Chocolat currently?

Comment: This is a programming question and, as such, belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is not a programming question. This is a question about a user interface feature of a Mac application. Therefore it belongs here.

Comment: Did you try installing the extras or command line tools for Choclate? Their doucmentation is shady at best, IMO not worth $40+ at this point, I would try contacting the Developer for help...

Comment: Good idea MrDaniel. I had not thought of/installed that. Unfortunately, after selecting the "Install Command Line Tool…" menu item, and running the installer, nothing has changed. Still no output in the app nor in Console.app.